# Validation before onNext() in Bootstrap Tour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am using [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) for a guided tutorial on how to use our tool. Upon clicking the `Next >>` button however, I would like to make sure some javascript variables are correct before allowing the user to continue.

How can I prevent the `onNext()` method from firing if certain conditions aren't met?

Comment: This plugin drives me crazy. Its buggy, no support, no answers..............